# How can I get values from list using

Tags: c#

the problem is:

I've 3 classes

```
public abstract class RelacionamentoComercial
{
    public string cod_usu { get; set; }
    public IList<Endereco> endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario: RelacionamentoComercial
{
    public string senha { get; set; }
    public string cod_est { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }

}
```

Im using DAO Connections so,

```
public Usuario Save(Usuario usuario)
{var table = abstractDAO.OpenTable(TableName);
        table .Seek(usuario.cod_usu);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = usuario.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propertyValue = property.GetValue(usuario, null);
            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
                if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(int))
                    table.PutInteger(property.Name.ToUpper(), Convert.ToInt32(propertyValue));
                else if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(double))
                    table.PutDouble(property.Name.ToUpper(), Convert.ToDouble(propertyValue));
                else if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(bool))
                    table.PutBoolean(property.Name.ToUpper(), Convert.ToBoolean(propertyValue));
                else if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                    table.PutDate(property.Name.ToUpper(), Convert.ToDateTime(propertyValue));
                else if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(string))
                    table.PutString(property.Name.ToUpper(), Convert.ToString(propertyValue));
                else if (propertyValue.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                {
                   <<<< ? >>>>
                }
```

I want to obtain a List< Endereco > to save in Clientes, but i dont know how to do it, ive already tried with reflection

```
PropertyInfo[] propList = propertyValue.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList)
```

but useless,
if someone have a better thought, please

Comment: Give you a light? Why? Are you having a smoke?

Comment: Why are you even using reflection to begin with?

Comment: We need a dynamic saveDAO, this is the best we've found, getting the properties from model and adding in database, bcuz its the same names

Comment: better than using stored procedures and passing in arguments from an object?

Comment: We have like 300 models with like 500 lines each one, we're moving a delphi comercial software to .net, so we're trying a dynamic save, instead create a dao repeating the same arguments everytime, do you know how can we do it?thanks for trying help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying something like:

```
public static object ConvertList(List<object> value, Type type)
{
    var listType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
    return value.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, listType));
}
```

That should do the trick.